# How to make Text dynamically size itself to the container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

The above image is without using the `FittedBox` Widget, here the text overflows

[image]

The above image is with using the `FittedBox` Widget, here all the text contained in a single line

```
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: FittedBox(child: Text("hello" * 20))),
```

How to make the `Text` Widget dynamically size itself to the available space, so that all the text is visible (without any scrollable widget)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is package called [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

which is used to automatically size text to the given bounds, bounds cannot be row or column, they should be wrapped with either Expanded or Flexible widget

```
AutoSizeText(
  'hello'*20,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

you can give `minFontSize` to adjust it to the least size, while if the Widget cannot fit more text then it uses ellipsis or any mentioned `textOverflow` method

Answer (score 2):

[auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)
You can use this plugin. minFont, maxlines can be set in this widget.
It is a sample code snippet;

```
AutoSizeText(
  'A really long String',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  minFontSize: 18,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can achieve that without any extra dependencies, just use FittedBox inside Container with desired width

```
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            width: 120,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              child: Text(
                "here is the long text to be scaled down",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Alternatively, you can use Flexible inside Container with desired width, this will make the text to be wrapped to be multiline as needed

```
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            width: 120,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
            child: Flexible(
              child: Text(
                "here is the long text to be wrapped to be multiline as needed",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```